# problem to install psycopg2 because of my macbook m1 chip

Tags: python, django, macos, pycharm, psycopg2

i bought a macbook to train me how to use mac os environment, i want to make django app on pycharm but i'm not able to intall psycopg2 because of my processor M1 et want to know if there is a solution or did we need to wait an update from apple or psycopg2 creator ?

i remember a soluton i tried few weeks ago, it was about changing something in my mac settings, i belive it was called "rosetta" maybe or something like that but doesnt work or i doesnt dont it well.

thank you for help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may want to look at [these threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/psycopg2%2bmacos?tab=Votes) they deal with similar problems.

Comment: You can install https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/

Comment: There's a Github [issue](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1200) dedicated to MacOs installs.

Comment: Try to follow what @ruddra told. `pip install psycopg2-binary`.

Comment: okay i'm gonna try it but it said that's not a good way to install psycopg2 binary for production, it is really a problem ?